# Scrape page then count the number of divs of a certain class and echo that number

Tags: php, html, domdocument

Hi all seem to be hitting a wall here, I'm tryng to create a simple script that counts the number of servers currently running this map by scraping the page, counting the divs with the class ".row ark_srv1" then echoing that number.

Problem: Script returns 0

Here is what I have managed to slap together so far:

```
<?php

$html_string = file_get_contents('toparkservers.com/1/search/?term=Umassoura'); 

function getElementsByClassName($elements, $className) {
    $matches = array();
    foreach($elements as $element) {
        if (!$element->hasAttribute('class')) {
            continue;
        }
        $classes = preg_split('/\s+/', $element->getAttribute('class'));
        if ( ! in_array($className, $classes)) {
            continue;
        }
        $matches[] = $element;
    }
    return $matches;
}

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
$divs = getElementsByClassName($dom->getElementsByTagName('.row ark_srv1'), '.row ark_srv1');
$length = $divs->length;

echo count($divs);

?>
```

Comment: `$dom->getElementsByTagName('.row ark_srv1')` - shouldn't this be `getElementsByClassName('.row ark_srv1')`? `.row` is a class, yes? `div` would be a "Tag Name"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative, why not use `xpath` to get the elements by class name:

```
$html_string = file_get_contents('http://toparkservers.com/1/search/?term=Umassoura'); 
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$class = 'row ark_srv1';
$elements = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, '{$class}')]");
echo 'elements found: ', $elements->length;
```

Comment: Much nicer. I was formulating the same example but got stuck at the invalid HTML :)

Comment: @RobbieAverill beat you to it :p

Answer (score 0):

When I'm parsing HTML, I like to use
[XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$divs= $xpath->query("//div[@class='className']");
echo count($divs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like to use [QueryPath](https://packagist.org/packages/querypath/querypath):

```
<?php

print html5qp('http://toparkservers.com/1/search/?term=Umassoura', '.row.ark_srv1')->length;
// 9
```